# Laravel hasmany function returns nothing

Tags: laravel

When i m using has many without select it returns all fields from userTrancastion table

*Invoicemodule.php*

```
$invoice = UserInvoiceDetail::with('transaction')
            ->select('Id','UserId','TotalPrice')
            ->where('UserId','=',$playerId)
            ->get();
            return $invoice;
```

*UserInvoiceDetail.php*

```
class UserInvoiceDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_invoice_details';
    protected $primaryKey ='Id';
    public function transaction() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserTransaction::class, 'InvoiceId');
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
"Invoices": 
[
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "UserId": 5,
            "TotalPrice": 110,
            "transaction": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "InvoiceId": 1,
                    "UserId": 5,
                    "ReferenceTransactionId": null,
                    "CategoryId": 1,
                    "ProductId": 140,
                    "Price": 5,
                    "Quantity": 5,
                    "CustomerId": 1,
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "InvoiceId": 1,
                    "UserId": 5,
                    "ReferenceTransactionId": null,
                    "CategoryId": 2,
                    "ProductId": 3,
                    "Price": 15,
                    "Quantity": 3,
                    "CustomerId": 1,
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

But When i m using has many with select it returns nothing userTrancastion table

*UserInvoiceDetail.php*

```
class UserInvoiceDetail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_invoice_details';
    protected $primaryKey ='Id';

    public function transaction() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserTransaction::class, 'InvoiceId')->select('user_transactions.Id','user_transactions.ProductId');
    }

}
```

Output

```
"Invoices": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "UserId": 5,
        "TotalPrice": 110,
        "transaction": []
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "UserId": 5,
        "TotalPrice": 110,
        "transaction": []
    }
]
```

why this is happening, I want to use join in transaction() function, so i need  only selective fields. 
How can use select with hasmany()?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relation need to the column that by which it related so add `InvoiceId`
also, it doesn't need to add `user_transactions`

```
public function transaction() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserTransaction::class, 'InvoiceId')->select('Id','ProductId','InvoiceId');
}
```